# Opera Will No Longer Log Me In To Gmail

Tags: passwords, gmail, opera

Since this morning, my opera (11.51 on Snow Leopard) will not log me in to any of my gmail accounts.

The wand button just appears inactive on the gmail login page.

However, it works for facebook and other sites.

I can see the list of gmail accounts in the password manager.

Please help. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Gmail changed the authentication page some time ago (possibly around the time that you experienced this) so Opera don't recognize it as the one he stored the passwords for. Retyping my passwords and teaching it to Opera again worked for me.